# How can i pass all integers i this loop and stop before the last line

Tags: java, linked-list, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer, parseint

this is my input

```
first line
5 6
3 4
2 3
2 5
1 0
word 2 2 4
```

i need to add all the integers to a graph but not the last line (word 1 2 4)..

i have splitted the first line (first line etc.) and put them in a arraylist.. No problem there

but then i have this for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < (amount of lines); i++) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
        graph.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    }
```

i cant write in the code how many times i want it to put integers, because my code should run generally with other inputs...
How can i make it stop before the last line, i still need to be able to use the last bufferreaderline

Comment: It looks like everything is on one line based on your question.

Comment: Are there two strings per line?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the last line is not needed?

Comment: When you call in.readLine() in the for loop, do you have called it before, for the first line? And what are the first and last line for?

Comment: Is the last line going to always start with "taetvenskab"?

Comment: This is **not** a site where people do your homework. Purposefully defacing questions and answers to avoid getting caught is not proper etiquette. It is better to post a reduced problem that will answer your question and remain useful. That way, the question can still be valid for other users and help the site out.

Comment: ok, sorry... i will aks useful questions in the future

Comment: I didnt ask for anybody to do my homework, i had a specific question as you can see, i couldnt loop something in my code
but i will ask more concrete next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `try-catch`:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String lastLine = "";

    try {
        while ((lastLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(lastLine);
            graph.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken()), 
                          Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken()));
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

    System.out.println(lastLine);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you always have one first line to create the graph, and a last line to do whatever. What you want to iterate over for adding Edges to the Graph are the lines between first an last.
I hope I'm guessing right.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
/* Iterating over the whole input first*/
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}

String firstLine = lines.get(0);
String lastLine = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);

StringTokenizer stok = new StringTokenizer(firstLine);
ArrayList<String> pax = new ArrayList<String>();
while(stok.hasMoreTokens()){
    pax.add(stok.nextToken());        
}

int v = pax.size();
Graaph graph = new Graaph(V);

/* Create the edges */
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size()-1; i++) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
    graph.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),  
        Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
}
```

This assumes that your input is not empty, but I guess you can handle that.
I hope this helps.